# How can I make the container "shrink-wrap" in IE7 when I'm floating children both left and right?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Here is an example of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/ryfvn/

In IE7 the container becomes full-width and loses his shrink-wrap. This does not happen if both the children are floated left, or if both of them are floated right.

Comment: Interesting problem. I don't have a real solution, but I'll say that you've essentially got 3 elements, all floated, with no widths specified on any of them. That sort of thing seems like a recipe for inconsistency across browsers. I'd float the inner divs both the same direction just to make it work, and tweak it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and couldn't find an answer using float right, but I was able to get the same effect using **absolute positioning**.

http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/QSr6K/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">content</div>
    <div class="right">content</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .container {
            float: left;
            padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
            background-color: green;
            position:relative;
    }

    .left {
            float: left;
            background-color: red;
    }

    .right {
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add a width to your `.container` element.

Comment: If it had a width, it wouldn't shrink-wrap.